# How to show generic types in C# XML summary

Tags: c#, generics, summary

```
/// <summary>
/// Something about this generic method which works with ??? type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">∙∙∙</typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
public T Foo<T>()
{
    ∙∙∙
}
```

Is it possible to write a comment in the summary tag to show current given generic type. (as visual-studio does)?

(**e.g.** We can see `Something about this generic method which works with string type.` in the tooltip of `Foo<string>()`)

Comment: won't that be misleading?

Comment: In some cases not, I guess so.

Comment: @HarisHasan For example we will be able to see this tip for `elementName1` (`"xxx"`) parameter: `The element name of type bool` in `Foo<T1, T2>(string elementName1, string elementName2)` with `Foo<bool, int>("xxx", "yyy")`. Isn't this helpful?

Answer (score 6):

this tag should do this `<typeparamref name="T"/>`

[Recommended Tags for Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx)

Comment: I'd tried this before with no success! It's useful in case of refactoring (renaming) type-parameter name to be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **GhostDoc**. [GhostDoc Link](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). Using short cut key Ctrl + Shift + d
on method. It's generate documentation.

Comment: For Method look like this: /// <summary>
  /// Gets the specified id.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="id">The id.</param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public string Get(int id)
  {
   return "value";
  }

Comment: I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641364/c-sharp-documentation-generator in stackoverflow. You might have to edit return: /// <summary>
  /// Serializes the object.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the object implementing.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="objectToSerialize">The object to serialize.</param>
  /// <returns>Returns serialize string.</returns>
  public string SerializeObject<T>(T objectToSerialize)

Comment: Thanks @Mvcdev. I checked them out, but I couldn't find any related answer. Would you mind bringing a specific example?

Comment: @Mimi I did put two example above. I am still not understand what specific example you are looking for?

Comment: Please pay attention that the question is about the summary tag content for a generic method. Your first example isn't about a generic method and the second one has no generic related content in summary tag: _Serializes the object._ I expected something like: _Serializes the object of type <xxx>T</xxx>._ to be appeared in the tooltip as: _Serializes the object of type string._ if you invoked it as: SerializeObject("some value"). NOTE: _xxx_ is the tag which I'm looking for.

Comment: How about now? /// <summary>
  /// Deserializes the object.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the object implementing.</typeparam>
  /// <param name="objectToDeserialize">The object to deserialize.</param>
  /// <returns>
  /// Returns deserilazie object.
  /// </returns>
  public T DeserializeObject<T>(string objectToDeserialize) If not then i am out of your help.

Comment: Nope! Dear @Mvcdev, this new example is all just similar to your second one. (The question is not about **<return></return>** tag.) As I discussed above, I'm looking for some special tag right within content of **<summary></summary>** tag to show what passed as generic argument to the method. As far as I know, there is currently not such a tag in XML summary. I just guess this feature can be useful and hope to be added later. Nonetheless, any work-around is appreciated!